# storing soft links under apache document root

Tags: linux, apache

can i store soft links under apache document root `(/var/www/html)` and keep the actual files outside the document root in an another filesytem? i have 4 filesystems in my hard disk 3 NTFS and 1 ext3 (dual operating system). my apache document root is in ext3. can i store the actual files in the NTFS partition and keep only soft links(or hard links) under apache document root? i tried this by making hard links to file stored in NTFS filesystem but it gave errors(the filesystem was mounted).  i tried with soft links but it did not worked. can somebody tell me if its possible and how? thanks

Comment: FYI you can't make hard links from one filesystem to another. Hard links only work inter-filesystem because they rely on a shared inode.

Answer (score 0):

Apache has a directive that controls whether or not it follows symlinks called FollowSymLinks. Read about it here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: can u help me with this [](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168558/unable-to-scrape-content-from-a-website)