# unable to scrape content from a website

Tags: php, xhtml, web-scraping, xml-namespaces, domxpath

I am trying to scrap some content from a website but the code below is not working(not showing any output).
here is the code

```
$url="some url";
$otherHeaders="";   //here i am using some other headers like content-type,userAgent,etc
some curl to get the webpage
...
..
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$content=curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);

$page=new DOMDocument();
$xpath=new DOMXPath($page); 
$content=getXHTML($content);  //this is a tidy function to convert bad html to xhtml 
$page->loadHTML($content);    // its okay till here when i echo $page->saveHTML the page is displayed

$path1="//body/table[4]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]";
$path2="//body/table[4]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]";

$item1=$xpath->query($path1);
$item2=$xpath->query($path2);

echo $item1->length;      //this shows zero 
echo $item2->length;      //this shows zero

foreach($item1 as $t)
echo $t->nodeValue;    //doesnt show anything
foreach($item2 as $p)
echo $p->nodeValue;    //doesnt show anything
```

i am sure there is something wrong with the above `xpath` code. the `xpaths` are correct. I have checked the above `xpaths` with `FirePath (a firefox addon)`. I know i am missing something very silly here but i cant make out. Please help.
I have checked similar code for scraping links from `Wikipedia`(definitely the `xpaths` are different) and it works nicely.
So i dont understand why the above code does not work for the other `URLs`. I am cleaning the `HTML` content with `Tidy` so i dont there is a problem with xpath not geeting the HTML right? 
i have checked the length of the `nodelist` after  `$item1=$xpath->query($path1)` which is `0` which means something is going wrong with `$xpath->query` because the `xpaths` are correct as i have checked with `FirePath`
I have modified my code a bit as pointed out and used `loadXML` instead of `loadHTML`.
but this gives me error as `Entity 'nbsp' not defined in Entity` so i used the `libxml` option `LIBXML_NOENT` to substitute entities but still the errors remain.

Comment: What do `$t->nodeName` and `$t->nodeType` output in your foreach loops at the end?

Comment: Can you please link to the webpage you are trying to parse?

Comment: @Michael: they both dont output anything. the browser window is just blank.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two recommendations that will help construct and use the right XPath expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question reminds me that a lot of times the solution to a problem lies in simplicity and not complications. i was trying `namespaces`,`error corrections`,etc but the solution just demanded close inspection of the code.
the problem with my code was the order of `loadHTML()` and `xpath initialization`. initially the order was

```
$xpath=new DOMXPath($page);
$page->loadHTML($content);
```

by doing this i was actually initializing `xapth` on an empty document. now reversing the order by first loading the `dom` with the `html` and then initializing the `xpath` i was able to get the desired results. Also as suggested that by removing the `tbody`element from `xpath` as `firefox` automatically inserts it. so the correct `xpath` should be

```
$path1="//body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]";
$path2="//body/table[4]/tr[1]/td[4]";
```

thanks to everyone for their suggestions and bearing this.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are missing something very basic: It's XHTML, so you must register (and use!) the proper [namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) before you can expect to get results.

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('x', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');

$path1="//x:body/x:table[4]/x:tbody/x:tr[3]/x:td[4]";
$path2="//x:body/x:table[4]/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td[4]";

$item1=$xpath->query($path1);
$item2=$xpath->query($path2);
```

Comment: @Tomalak: when i modify my code as above it gives me an error as `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\rtu\rtu_results.php on line 24` line 24 here is the line `$path1="//x:body/x:table[4]/x:tbody/x:tr[3]/x:td[4]";` i have scraped web pages like this before from my `localhost` but never needed namespace

Comment: @Lovesh that syntax error would indicate you're missing a `;` on the previous line.

Comment: @Marc: You are right, I missed a semi-colon. Thanks. @lovesh: A little more independent thinking, please. ;-) I'm sure that's not the first time you see such an error.

Comment: @Marc: I have added the semicolon to the line `$xpath->registerNamespace('x', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')` and it doesnt give the error now but its not showing the output yet

Comment: @lovesh: Please test with a simple `"//x:table"` as an XPath expression. If this gives you all tables in your document, then the namespace is working but your own XPath expression is wrong. If this is not working then the namespace `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` is not the right one and you must check against your XHTML document what namespace it is actually using.

Comment: Check that your `getXHTML()` function is actually returning something. If it's mangling the input, then xpath won't help you

Comment: @Marc B: the `getXHTML()` function is returning the XHTML after cleaning the HTML

Comment: The XHTML may not have the correct xmlns. Check the value of `$page->documentElement->namespaceURI` and if it is not null you should pass that value into `registerNamespace()`.

Comment: @cbuckley:`$page->documentElement->namespaceURI` is null. i mean it is not showing any output

Comment: @Tomalak: i am using this namespace as `$xpath->registerNamespace('x', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')` and i used the xpath as `//x:table` but again the `xpath->query` is returning a nodelist with 0 length and the browser window is still blank. as i am converting a page from another website to `xhtml` bu using `tidy`, how can i know the namespace used by that site and do namespaces change once the `html` goes through `Tidy`

Comment: @Tomalak: I have checked the namespace of the document by viewing source in `firefox` it is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. i used this namespace in `registernamespace` but still no output

Comment: @lovesh: You do not provide enough information. Write a small-but-complete code example that reproducibly shows the error. Otherwise nobody here can help you. You should have done this from the start.

Comment: @Tomalak: ok i will show you the complete code. actually its like sumbmitting a value to a form and then i have to scrap the content generated dynamicall. i will also provide the urls taht i am scraping to

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the problem is somehow related to XPath and namespaces. Php manual revealed an interesting [user comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php#83712)

> If you've registered your namespaces,
>   loaded your XHTML, etc., into your
>   XPath's DOMDocument object and
>   *still* can't get it to work,
>   check to make sure you haven't used
>   the DOMDocument's loadHTML() or
>   loadHTMLFile() function. For XHTML
>   *always use the XML versions*,
>   otherwise your XPath will never, ever
>   work.

Your code uses `loadHTML()`

```
$content=getXHTML($content);  //this is a tidy function to convert bad html to xhtml 
$page->loadHTML($content);    // its okay till here when i echo $page->saveHTML the page is displayed
```

HTML is not namespace aware so `loadHTML()` might not set the namespaces on the elements of the document object even though the original document (or the XHTML outputted by Tidy) had them.

Because you use Tidy to convert the document to XHTML, I guess you could safely use `loadXML()` without running into parsing errors. Note that it will require that the input is well-formed XML. Also it might not be aware of HTML predefined entities like `&nbsp;` and if that is the case, it can't replace the entities with their correct character values. If such problem arises, try setting different options for `loadXML()`.

Comment: +1 Recommended in private e-mail. Should have followed it up here, but thanks for adding the user comment.

Comment: thanks for this. you are right, using `loadXML` is giving errors  `Entity 'nbsp' not defined in Entity, line: 212 in filename on line 10` where line 10 is the line with loadXML. i tried using options for `loadXML` like `$page->loadXML($content,LIBXML_NOENT);` for substituting entities but the errors remain. can u tell me which option or combination of options can make this work?

Comment: @lovesh: Sorry, I'm not familiar with those options. Other possibility to fix entity problems is to check if Tidy can do the entity replacement.

Answer (score 2):

**I have heard that FireFox adds a `tbody` element if such isn't present**.

In addition to or independently of  @Tomalak's advice, **try the XPath expressions with the `/tbody` location step removed.**

**Also, use another tool as [the XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)** to construct correct XPath expressions and see immediately what they are selecting.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: i tried your suggestion but it giving an error as `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\rtu\rtu_results.php on line 27` where line 27 is `$path1="//body/table[4]/tr[3]/td[4]";`

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: I tried the `xpath` with `google chrome` but i get the same error

Comment: @lovesh: The XPath expression is syntactically correct -- the syntax error should be in your PHP statement.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: I think the php is correct too because i have scraped content from other pages but i have done it from `localhost` that is my own web server in the same way.i used to save pages to my disk first.any other suggestion that u have got? can it happen like you can forward my question to someone who can help?

Comment: @lovesh: I don't know anytjing about PHP. As far as XPath is concerned, I have answered your question completely. You can test the proposed solution on a static XML document to verify it is working. If this is confirmed then the problem is in your dynamic access to the document and I recommend that you ask a different question using appropriate question-tags specifically about this problem. I would be glad to further assist with any XPath-related issues.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: Thanks for the help

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: can i post this same question again because somebody might close it calling it a duplicate? is there some other way to bring people's attention to this question?

Comment: @lovesh: Why should you post the question again? Better edit it and add new, relevant information. For example, provide a sample XML file -- as minimal as possible. Then many people will be able to help.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: can i do something else to get more people's attention to this question? I am stuck on this for long. I have mdified my question to include some additional test that i did

Comment: I don't know much, if anything, about PHP, but you're saying it does not work, and it generally helps if you say what happens, what you expected, and what you tried to fix the problem. Just saying "it doesn't work" is understood by many as too vague to bother helping you with. In this case, did you try changing the xpath queries gradually up from nothing to what you have in your question, to figure out which particular node(s) you're not locating?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: as i have mentioned in this post above that there is no output and and i have tried implementing the above suggestions but nothing works. i expect to see the data from the selected fields and this code works for wikipedia but its not working for some urls.

Answer (score 0):

(Try the following both in combination with and separately from the other answers, as they are other possible caveats.)

If your XPath isn't working, try applying just parts of it to make sure you are indeed following the right path. So do something like:

```
$path1="//body";
$item1 = $xpath->query($path1);

foreach ($item1 as $t) {
    // to see the full XML of the returned node, as the nodeValue may be empty
    echo $t->ownerDocument->saveXML($t); 
}
```

Then keep increasing your XPath to the location you want.

Also, if you find that nodeValue and textContent of your nodes are empty, you should make sure that you are loading into the DOMDocument with the correct encoding (e.g. if the cURL response returns UTF-8, you'll need to pass 'UTF-8' as the second parameter when constructing your DOMDOcument).

Comment: i tried your suggestion but it is not showing any outpt. Now i am absolutely sure what the problem is. `$xpath->query($path1);
` is not getting the `xpath`. can u imagine why?

Comment: the DOMDocument is being loaded properly as i have checked with $page->saveHTML(). it is displaying the page in the browser

Comment: How about instead of using XPaths for testing, you check the element returned by `$page->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)`? You can keep following the path in the same way by chaining those methods.

Comment: how do i find the encoding of the cURL response?

Comment: It will (hopefully) be in the `Content-Type` response header. You'll need to do something like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` and then split the headers from the body with `list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $content, 2);`. Have a look at http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/php-34/getting-response-header-php-curl-request-590248.html for more info.